# How to use Markov-Kakutani fixed point theorem to show that abelian groups are amenable?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, measure-theory, convex-analysis, fixed-point-theorems

Recall that a group $\Gamma$ is ***[amenable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amenable_group)*** if there exists a state $\mu$ on $l^{\infty}(\Gamma)$ which is invariant under the left translation action: for all $s\in \Gamma$ and $f\in l^{\infty}(\Gamma)$, $\mu(s.f)=\mu(f)$.

**If the group is abelian, as the [Markov-Kakutani fixed point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_fixed-point_theorem) easily implies the group is amenable.**

Well, my question is: what is Markov-Kakutani fixed point theorem here (I am no familiar with fixed point theory)? And how to use it to verify the abelian group is amenable?

Comment: Searching for ["Kakutani fixed point theorem" abelian amenable](http://books.google.com/books?q=%22Kakutani+fixed+point+theorem%22+abelian+amenable) in Google Books returns, for example, [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=N-LSFFaHTKwC&pg=PA92). Maybe it will help. (Or some of other sources found there.)

Comment: There is also a MO thread: [Why are abelian groups amenable?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/12169/why-are-abelian-groups-amenable)

Comment: BTW there is also ([tag:amenability]) tag, which seems reasonable for this question. But there can be at most 5 tags for each question, and I am not sure, which of the 5 you've chosen would be suitable candidate to be replaced..

Comment: @Martin Sleziak Could you tell me what is Markov-Kakutani fixed point theorem firstly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first copy the proof from Ceccherini-Silberstein, Coornaert: Cellular Automata and Groups [page 92](http://books.google.com/books?id=N-LSFFaHTKwC&pg=PA92) and then give some explanations. This is basically the same proof as the proof in [this answer on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12169/why-are-abelian-groups-amenable/118434#118434).

> **Theorem 4.6.1.** Every abelian group is amenable.
>
> *Proof.* Let $G$ be an abelian group. Equip $(\ell^\infty(G))^*$ with the weak-* topology.
> By Theorem 4.2.1, the set $\mathcal M(G)$ is a nonempty convex compact subset of $(\ell^\infty(G))^*$.
> On the other hand, it follows from Proposition 4.3.1 that the action of $G$ on $\mathcal M(G)$ is affine and continuous (note that the left and the right actions coincide since $G$ is Abelian).
> By applying the Markov-Kakutani fixed-point Theorem (Theorem G.1.1), we deduce that G has at least one fixed point in $\mathcal M(G)$. Such a fixed point is clearly a bi-invariant mean on $G$. This shows that $G$ is amenable.

Here $\mathcal M(G)$ denotes the set of all means on $G$, i.e., all positive functionals $\varphi \in (\ell^\infty)^*$ such that $\|\varphi\|=1$.

The above proof starts by the claim that this set is non-empty convex and compact.

It is nonempty, since for example the evaluation functional $\varphi(f)=f(e_G)$ is a mean on $G$. (It is the mean corresponding to the finitely additive measure $\mu$ defined by $\mu(A)=1$ if $e_G\in A$ and $\mu(A)=0$ otherwise.)

It is easy to see that convex combination of positive functionals is convex. Also showing that a unit ball of a linear normed space is convex is easy.

Compactness can be shown using [Banach-Alaoglu theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach-Alaoglu_theorem). This theorem says that the unit ball of $(\ell^\infty)^*$  with the weak-* topology is compact. Now it suffices to show that $\mathcal M(G)$ is closed subset of this unit ball. Perhaps the simplest approach is to show that a limit of any convergent net of means is again a mean.

Now we have a [group action](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action) of $G$ on $\mathcal M(G)$ defined by $g\varphi(x)=\varphi(g^{-1}x)$. (You only need to verify, that that each $g\varphi$ is again in $\mathcal G$ and this is indeed a group action.)

Each of the maps $\varphi\mapsto g\varphi$ is a linear continuous map $\mathcal M(G)\to\mathcal M(G)$. Moreover, since the group $G$ is commutative, these maps commute with each other.

[Markov-Kakutani fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_fixed-point_theorem) says that if we have a system of maps from $C$ to $C$, such that each of these maps is affine and the maps commute with each other, where the set $C$ is non-empty compact convex subset of some Hausdorff topological vector space, then there exists a common fixed point of all these maps.

In this case all assumptions of this theorem are fulfilled, so there is a mean $\varphi\in\mathcal M(G)$, which is not changed any of the shifts $\varphi\mapsto\varphi g$, i.e. $g\varphi=\varphi$ for each $g\in G$. This means that $\varphi$ is an invariant mean on $G$.

Comment: Disclaimer: I have never studied amenable groups in detail (but I have seen them mentioned occasionally and I knew some of the equivalent conditions for a group to be amenable). And also this is the first time I am using Markov-Kakutani. So take what I wrote with a grain of salt. But I have no doubt that there are users on this site who are more experienced in this topic and they can point out if my posts has any inaccuracies or if I have overcomplicated something or skipped some steps I should not have.

Comment: It is also my first time to see the amenalbe and Markov-Kakutani. Thanks for your patience and help very much. :P